# How many different vectors can there be?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I need some help with the following combinatorics problem:

Consider a vector $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$ where $x_i\in \mathbb{N}$ $\forall i$ and $x_1+x_2+...+x_r = n\in \mathbb{N}.$
How many different vectors are possible?

I tried to think about how many ways there are to pick the components of the vector but couldn't get much done. The correct answer should be $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: [A similar and more general question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429561/number-of-solutions-of-x-1x-2-dotsx-k-n-with-x-i-le-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vector corresponds to the number of ways to distribute $n$ identical balls into $r$ distinct boxes, where each box has at least one ball.

First place $1$ ball into each of the $r$ boxes, so that each box is non-empty. Now, $n - r$ balls remain. Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), there are $$\binom{n - r + (r - 1)}{ r - 1} = \binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$$
ways to distribute the remaining balls into the boxes.