# Number of non negative integer solutions with additional restriction

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Find the number of non negative integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+....x_k=n$$ with the additional constraints $$x_i < s,  \forall i \in [1,k], i\in Z$$

---

This is how I tried.

1. The number of non negative integer solutions to
   $x_1+x_2+....x_k=n$ without the constraints is: (Call it $A_0$)

$$ n+k-1 \choose k-1 $$

This can be found using standard ball & stick argument.

2. We need to apply Inclusion Exclusion Principle Now:

Let $P_i$ be the property that the $i^{th}$ $x_i$ violates the constraints. Then let $A_i$ be the set of non negative integer solution of $x_1+x_2+....x_k=n$ with the additional constraint $x_i < s$ does not hold. i.e $x_i \geq s$

Then |$A_i$| is $n-s+k-1 \choose k-1$ (Is this correct?)

3. The number of required solution is then:
   $$|A_0| - |A_1 \cap .... \cap A_K|$$
4. Then by Inclusion Exclusion Principle:
   $|A_1 \cap .... \cap A_K|$ can be calculated

Now how to proceed from here? How do I get my final answer in terms of $n,k,s$

Comment: Fix your title.... "non-integer"????

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry. Fixed it. I meant non negative integer

Comment: PIE gives it directly. It's easier to set it up where $B_i$ is the set of solutions with the constraint $ x_i \geq s$, because we can apply stars and bars to a slightly modified version, getting the value that you want. With that, we'd have to modify 3.

Comment: @CalvinLin I have defined $A_i$ and changed (3) as per your comment. I have also calculated |$A_i$|. I still dont understand how can i apply PIE to get answer in form on $n,k,s$

Comment: you'd want $ \Cup A_i$ right? How do you use PIE to calculate that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n$ with $x_i\le r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429561/number-of-solutions-of-x-1x-2-dotsx-k-n-with-x-i-le-r)

Comment: @FNishat Yes! Thanks! I was able to reach the answer using PIE. I shall add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

To approach this problem, what we must understand first is how the formula for the number of non-negative integral solutions with no restrictions is derived. It all stems from the Binomial Theorem. Consider this- you have a polynomial $$(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + ...)^n$$ The coefficient of $x^r$ in this expression is actually the number of non-negative integral solutions of $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n = r $$ How is that? Well, consider how the term $x^r$ is to be obtained. We choose *one particular term* $x^a$ from each of the *n factors* and at the end, after multiplying all the chosen terms from each bracket the *resultant power of x must be **r***. In other words, $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n = r $. Note that here $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ are all non-negative as we have no negative power in our factors. Suppose this choosing of terms can be done in $k$ different ways. Then each of those choices would contribute one $x^r$ to the final expression. Which implies that the coefficient of $x^r$ in this polynomial would be $k$, which is our required answer.

Putting this idea into action, we obtain $$\begin{aligned}k &= \text{coefficient of } x^r \text{ in } (x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + ...)^n \\ &= \text{coefficient of } x^r \text{ in } \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n \text{ [Assuming x<1 WLOG as x plays no role in our derivation]} \\ &= \text{coefficient of } x^r \text{ in } (1-x)^{-n} \\ &=  ^{r+n-1}C_{n-1} \end{aligned}$$ The above result can be found in any high-school algebra textbook. Refer [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/312629/prove-that-the-coefficient-of-x-r-in-1-x-n-is-n-r-1cr) for the proof.

Now, once we have understood the above derivation, this problem can be solved quite easily. What we need to do is *find the coefficient of* $x^r$ *in* $$ (x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^{s-1})^n $$ which simplifies to $$\begin{aligned} \text{coefficient of } x^r \text{ in } \left(\frac{1 \times (1-x^s)}{1-x}\right)^n  &= \text{coefficient of } x^r \text{ in } (1-x^s)^n (1-x)^{-n}\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, the answer you desire in terms of $n,k,s$ according to your definition is simply $$ \text{coefficient of } x^n \text{ in } (1-x^s)^k (1-x)^{-k} $$To proceed further, we would need specific values of $n,k,s$ and evaluate the coefficient according to the standard algebra textbook process.

Comment: I was looking for an answer using PIE. It is possible to get a closed form answer using PIE. But, thanks for the alternate approach!