# Ways to calculate the distribution of the sum of n dice rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Is there any other way that doesn't involve manually listing out every way?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/993044#993044). There are some others questions about the same topic.

Comment: Please make the body of your Question as self-contained as possible, not relying on the title alone to bear the burden of problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The MGF of a uniform distribution over $\{1,\dots,6\}$ is $$\varphi(t) = \frac{e^t-e^{7t}}{6(1-e^t)}$$
so the MGF of the sum $X$ of $n$ independent such r.v.'s $X_1,\dots,X_n$ will be
$$\Phi(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX_1}]^n=
\left(\frac{e^t-e^{7t}}{6(1-e^t)}\right)^n$$
is that enough for you, or do you want a closed-form (provided there even is one)? The above will allow you, via manipulations and very enjoyable differentiations, to find the probability of any outcome.

(For what it's worth, such a distribution can also be seen as a [very special case of $k$-SIIRV](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/papers/focs13.html), for $k=6$).