# Probability of rolling a specific average (4, 5) with a six-sided die over n-rolls

Tags: probability, dice, average

I'm wondering if someone could help me answer the following.

How could you estimate the probability of rolling a specific average value (e.g., rolling an average of 4 or of 5) over a set number of rolls (n).

For instance, how could you calculate the probability of:

1. Averaging exactly (or greater) than 4 over 15 rolls (n=15).
2. Averaging exactly (or greater) than 5 over 15 rolls (n-15).

I realize there is a different between exact and greater than claims, but I'd be interested in figuring out how estimate both.

Thanks.

Comment: An exact solution is setting $S:=n\cdot A$, where $A$ is your desired average. After follow [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/993044#993044) and the probability that you want, for some fixed $A$ in $n$ rolls, is $[x^S]g(x)/6^n$ (for fair dice of six sides). To get probabilities "more or equal than $A$" you only need add all the probabilities of all of these averages. For an estimation you can use the CDF of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.**

For the number of spots $D$ on a single roll of a fair die,
$E(D) = 3.5$ and $SD(D) \approx 1.7.$

For the average $\bar D_{15}$ of 15 rolls, $\mu =E(\bar D_{15}) = 3.5$ and
$\sigma =SD(\bar D_{15}) = SD(D)/\sqrt{15}
\approx 0.44.$

Because $4$ is roughly $\mu + \sigma$,
the probability to have the average for 15 dice above 4 will be around 15%.
(And an average above 5 will be very rare, maybe about 0.0003.)

Is this the question you intended to ask? If so, the distribution of $\bar D_{15}$
is very nearly normal; you can use that to get more precise answers.