# what is the probability of sum of five dice is being 14?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Five fair six-sided dice are rolled. The probability that the sum of the result being 14 is ?

My solution : I started it with this following method

$$\sum_{d_{1}=1}^{6}\sum_{d_{2}=1}^{6}\sum_{d_{3}=1}^{6}\sum_{d_{4}=1}^{6}\sum_{d_{5}=1}^{6} \left[z\right]^{14}z^{d_{1}+d_{2}+d_{3}+d_{4}+d_{5}}$$

And I obtained 85/972 as the solution , Is that right ?

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290090/probability-that-the-sum-of-k-dice-is-n) for an "alternative" way to count the valid cases.

Comment: Write $\left[\,{z^{14}}\,\right]$ instead of $\require{cancel}\cancel{\left[\,{z}\,\right]^{\color{#f00}{14}}}$.

Answer (score 3):

From stars and bars the number of $n$-tuples of natural numbers summing to $k$ is given by $\binom {k-1}{n-1} $

The number of 5-tuples of natural numbers summing to 14 is given by $\binom {13}4 = 715 $

some of these will contain a number greater than six. To get the number of 5-tuples that correspond to 5 rolls of a 6 sided die you need to subtract these from 715. It is fortunate that no 5-tuple summing to 14 can contain more than one element greater than 6.

- those that contain a 7 must also have 4 other natural numbers summing to 7,
- there are $5\binom 63$ of these
- and $5\binom 53$ will contain an 8

Total 5-tuples summing to 14 for which no element is greater then 6 is given by

$$ N  = \binom {13}4-5\binom 63 -5\binom 53 -5\binom 43 -5\binom 33$$
where the last term comes from the 5-tuples containing one 10 and four 4's

$$ = 715 - 100-50-20-5=  540$$

Each 5-tuple has a probability of $(\frac 16)^5=\frac 1{7776}$

so the probability of summing to 14 is $\frac{540}{7776}= \frac 5{72}$

Comment: Thank you i just correcting my Answer even with different method I obtained same answer , thanks again youve been really helpful

Answer (score 2):

There are $6^5$ possible outcomes when five six-sided dice are rolled.

The number of outcomes in which the outcomes sum to $14$ is equal to the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 14 \tag{1}$$
in the positive integers subject to the constraints that $x_k \leq 6$ for $1 \leq k \leq 5$.  The number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers is given by the formula 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$
Hence, equation 1 has 
$$\binom{14 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{13}{4}$$
solutions.

From these, we must exclude those solutions in which one or more of the variables exceeds $6$.  Note that at most one variable may exceed $6$ since $2 \cdot 7 + 3 \cdot 1 = 17 > 14$.

Suppose $x_1 \geq 7$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 6$.  Then $x_1'$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 6$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 6 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 14\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 & = 8 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with
$$\binom{8 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{7}{4}$$
solutions.

By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions for each variable that could exceed $6$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 in which one of the five variables exceeds $6$ is 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{4}$$
Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 that satisfy the constraints is 
$$\binom{13}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{4} = 715 - 5 \cdot 35 = 540$$
Therefore, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{13}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{4}}{6^5} = \frac{540}{7776} = \frac{5}{72}$$