# If you roll $n$ six-sided dice what is the probability that the sum of the numbers you roll is multiple of $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, generating-functions

If you roll $n$  six-sided dice what is the probability that the sum of the numbers you roll is multiple of $k?$

I was wondering which combinatoric strategies would be useful to solve problems of these types. I often just find the probability for each multiple of $k$ and sum them up. Is there a more efficient way to approach this question?

Comment: That sounds as good a plan as any without more context or clarifications.  Your problem statement however could use a lot of work... Are you rolling one $n$-sided die?  Or are you rolling $n$ six-sided di**c**e?  If multiple dice, are you adding the results together or are you asking if there is at least one multiple of $k$ in the lot?

Comment: what exactly means "roll a number that is a multiple of $k$"? It means that the sum of the sides of the dice is a multiple of $k$? It means that there are some side repeated a multiple of $k$? Etc...

Comment: Sorry about that just fixed up the problem statement a bit now

Comment: I dont know a better way than use the formula that I wrote some time ago in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2290139/173262). You can write it as a sum of coefficients, if you like, but to evaluate these quantities efficiently probably the best way to do it is write some kind of recursion and run it in a program. In this case you can follow the steps to write a recursion using the $xD\log$ procedure described in page 22 of the free book *generatingfunctionology* of Wilf using the generating function $f$ described in the linked answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6\\
&=\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
then $f(x)^n$ is the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) of the number of ways to roll a given number on $n$ dice.

Thus, since
$$
\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{2\pi i\,jm/k}=[k\mid m]\tag{2}
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), the probability of rolling $m\pmod{k}$ on $n$ dice is
$$
\frac1{k6^n}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{-2\pi i\,jm/k}f\!\left(e^{2\pi i\,j/k}\right)^n\tag{3}
$$
For this question, we can set $m=0$ in $(3)$.

Comment: For $k = 6$ it's easy to check that the $j = 0$ summand is $6^n$ while the $j = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ summands are 0.  So you get that the probability of rolling a multiple of 6 is $1/6$.  There's an easy proof of this without using generating functions: no matter what you roll on the first $n - 1$ dice, there is exactly one choice of roll on the $n$th die that will give you a multiple of 6.   Similarly the probability of getting a total which is a multiple of 2 or 3 is $1/2$ or $1/3$ respectively.

Comment: Just wondering what is the computational complexity of this method?

Comment: @Anirudh: It depends on what you are counting. The number of exponentials computed is $3k$.