# Every combination of $14$ numbers that would add up to exactly $28$. Numbers can only be between $0$ and $3$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to find every combination of $14$ numbers that would add up to exactly $28$. Numbers can only be $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$.

I'm sorry if my wording is poor. I didn't study as much math as I would have liked too prior to getting into programming.

If your interested in the details. I'm trying to come up with an easier way to create spreadsheets to help with an rpg rule set I'm designing. Each possible combination represents a character class. The player allocates $28$ skill points among $14$ skills with no more than $3$ in each skill.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm ?

Comment: An algorithm would be great actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm in C, I had a snippet on hand to generate dynamic loops with any number of variables, so here it is:

[Try it at tio.run](https://tio.run/##rVRNj5swEL3zK6apuuKzG3ZzWJUlp55z6m0bVWDMMhRMhE0jtcpvT20MDt6seml8weMZv5n3ZjCJXgk5nz8iI81QUHjmosDuc7V1rKMGc3Xm3PvwFbnoMR8EhYcnOHTIBIeciiOlDOIN8J/YNByOKCqgGan0gQO@CVpDxgp4BP9eAUb/sSTCrw4LyMoSSUVdWQv4yAokNARl7DznjwNyKQMTZ9wfemmV7spdecl4UHa9i@k6AXzeRbH8BIFnoj4V4SrUmC@4n25cnJ5xyqvKfboVqW99hoK2lAmL1zWtkE/EFA@erkPFRVJJFI/RoYPV4hCkYNhoMid9G0tw@Yf04cmDnoqhZxPqRdwx/85LDP3vbHVLxhzboaE/8m4gzdRM0rVSATLKMFL3S2TvaVAnxpiUmsrXBqTQZk3TEXfnc/xNu9Kdwjxvod4/lDOiSahlVUZGraFr4rayUjUx8NqJDiSjjA0HW/FUjZveHytUnLfp@m1iaw7mFjiO7BHl4ssl9Qg24YBGgrs7uCooij3wAKNoyjzXbVLb6S3uQZBYDqVZnWIQJ7VUrZ5Vex9lgVTvU0vDep9chxota116PWupqds3To69kxJPkmuJyp7OI3yjkVWj1mbIXDW7y2EsaP4Sb/ahqll@k6sHaPHexBv93LzpuYLAvQwxJ7p36aM1QPYPIy@pnGG8mUda/8ewHgmfz38B)

However are you sure you want to generate that many configurations ?

It turns out there are $6\,472\,168$ of them.

Comment: Wow that's way more than I expected but it's what I needed to know. I probably won't name each combination in the game though lol.

Comment: I suggest you generate a fixed number $m$ of configurations. For each one do a loop from 1 to 28 and attribute +1 point at random for one of the 14 skills. If it is already 3, randomize again. Given the number of possibilities $n$, the $m$ configurations should statistically be all different for $m$ small in regards to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [to this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) where it is explained that
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}
{r}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \hfill \\
  k \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
  s - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} 
$$
You will find there also a recurrence formula.