# Counting restricted compositions

Tags: combinatorics

Given positive intgers $N$ and $S$ i need to count in how many ways $N$ can be decomposed as sum of $S$ positive integers not greater than $\frac{N}{2}$:
$$ N = x_1 + \dots + x_S, ~~~~ 0 \leq x_i \leq \frac{N}{2} $$

Two compositions are considered distinct if any of the summands has distinct values in them. For example, if $N = 4$ and $S = 3$ then there are 6 possible partitions:
$$(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 0, 2), (0, 2, 2)$$

I've derived a dynamic programming solution. Let $d_{ns}$ be the number of above defined compositions of number $n$ with $s$ summands (each not greater than $\frac{N}{2}$). Then
$$ d_{0s} = 1, ~~~ s \geq 0 $$
$$ d_{n0} = 0, ~~~ n > 0 $$
$$ d_{ns} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\max \left(n, \frac{N}{2} \right)}d_{n-k,s-1}, ~~~ sn > 0 $$

I wonder whether there is a more combinatorial solution to this problem. Perhaps some closed formula exists?

Comment: If you consider order to matter, then they are not called partitions but compositions.

Comment: @GCab Thanks for your comment. I'll change the name now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $N=2n$, note that without $N/2$ condition the number of solutions is ${N+S-1}\choose{S-1}$. You only need to subtract the cases where $x_i>n$ for some $i$. Hence the closed form is ${N+S-1}\choose{S-1}$-$S\cdot$ ${N+S-n-2}\choose{S-1}$. You don't need to add the cases where $x_i$ and $x_j$ are both larger than $n$ since that's impossible. Similarly you can compute the closed form for $N=2n+1$.

Comment: How did you get the binomial coefficient that you subtract? For fixed i x_i can be any of n + 1, ..., 2n so why is there N + s - n - 2?

Comment: The idea is to first give $n+1$ to $x_i$, and then distribute the remaining $N-(n+1)$. Hence the formula ${N-(n+1)+S-1}\choose{S-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [to this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) where it is explained that
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}
{r}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \begin{gathered}
  m \hfill \\
  k \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
  s - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} 
$$
You will find there also a recurrence formula.

In your case, clearly
$$
s = N\quad r = \left\lfloor {N/2} \right\rfloor \quad m = S
$$