# Probability that the sum of $6$ dice is $10$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question: Six dice are thrown independently. What is the probability of getting sum 10?

Attempt: There are total $6^6$ many possible cases. A number 6 can't appears in the sum so that total become 10.

1+1+1+1+1+5 there 6 way to happen this
2+2+2+2+2+2

Is there any better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use the stars and bars method to figure out how many ways six integers can add up to $4 = 10 - 6$

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le x_{\,k}  \le 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,6}  = 10 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le y_{\,k} \left( { \le 5} \right) \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + y_{\,6}  = 4 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and we can omit the upper bound on the admissible range for the $y$'s , since it is greater than the sum.

Thus the number of solutions is equal to the number of [*weak* compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
of $4$ into $6$ parts which is $$\binom{4+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{9}{5}$$

For a more general approach you may refer to [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_k$ be the result of the $k$th throw.  Then the number of favorable cases is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 10$$
in the positive integers subject to the restrictions that $x_k \leq 6$ for $1 \leq k \leq 6$.  However, none of the variables can exceed $6$ since $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 6 = 11 > 10$ is already too large.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of five addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, if we choose the second, third, fifth, eighth, and ninth spaces, we obtain 
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 + 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 3$, $x_5 = x_6 = 1$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can choose which five of the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones to fill with an addition sign, which is 
$$\binom{9}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are only 5 combinations to consider:

A.  1,1,1,1,1,5
B.  1,1,1,1,2,4
C.  1,1,1,1,3,3
D.  1,1,1,2,2,3
E.  1,1,2,2,2,2

A will occur 6! / (5! * 1!)      = 6 times
B will occur 6! / (4! * 1! * 1!) = 30 times
C will occur 6! / (4! * 2!)      = 15 times
D will occur 6! / (3! * 2! *1! ) = 60 times
E will occur 6! / ( 2! * 4! )    = 15 times

6 + 30 + 15 + 60 + 15 = 126 so the probability is 126 / 6^6 = approx. 0.27 %