# Combinatorics - What is the number of ways $K$ elements sum to $N$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $K$ elements between $1$ and $7$ (inclusive), how many ways can you arrange the elements s.t. their sum adds to $N$?

I can brute-force my way to counting the number of ways for small $K$ and $N$, but is there a general formula that addresses this problem? I feel like this is a commonly discussed problem, but I just don't know what the solution is. This  came out of something I'm working on (programming stuff). Thanks.

Comment: Generating Functions?

Comment: Integer partitions are hard. Perhaps start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this is via a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). We treat the powers of $x$ as the values of $k$

So, to represent the fact that each element can take on any value from 1 to 7, we introduce a polynomial with 1 term for each power between 1 and 7, i.e., $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7=\frac{x^8-1}{x-1}$. Then, since there are $k$ elements, we raise this polynomial to the $k$th power, and find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the result.

So, our answer will be the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$\bigg(\frac{x^8-1}{x-1}\bigg)^k$$

Comment: +1 Correct, but it's not clear that this helps the OP write an efficient implementation.

Comment: @EthanBolker Fair, but I don't think that's the purpose of this site, no? There are plenty of resources on optimizing generating functions computations.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't looking for code, just a general direction of where to look. Thank you.

Comment: @LeetCoder You can upvote the answer as well as accept it.

Comment: something wrong with the result for $(x+x^2+\cdots+x^7)$..!

Comment: @G Cab they are equivalent, but it's slightly easier computationally to compute $x^8-1$ compared to $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for
$$
\eqalign{
  & N_{\,b} (s,r,m) =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm No}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm integer}\;{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le x_{\,j}  \le r + 1 = 7 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m = K}  = s + K = N \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm No}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm integer}\;{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le y_{\,j}  \le r = 6 \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + y_{\,m = K}  = s = N - K \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \cr} 
$$
which is the [number of (weak) compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $s$, into exactly $m$ parts, restricted
to $\{0,1,\dots\,r\}$.

The general formula is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
as explained in detail [in this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) and in [this article](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm).