# Is it possible to determine how many combinations of numbers whose sum is between 2 boundaries?

Tags: combinatorics

So let's say I have x,y,z.  x is a number between 50 and 100, both y and z are a number between 0 and 50.

I want to know how many combinations of x, y and z will equal a value between 153 and 200.

I'm not sure how to approach this kind of problem. My preliminary search has lead me to the stars and bars method in combinatorics but I'm unable to rectify it with the boundaries i've given.

Comment: Is this a correct interpretation of your question; you want to count the number of ordered triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy $50\le x\le 100$, $0\le y\le 50$, $0\le z\le 50$, and $153\le x+y+z\le 200$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the usual strategy to employ with these problems, but this is how I would solve this:

$x$ is the odd variable out, with different bounds. What we can notice is that $x$ must be at least $53$. Let's make a quick list of what happens when we set $x$ to some numbers, and see how $y$ and $z$ depend on $x$ for a total of $153$.

```
x  ||  y  |  z
53 ||  50 |  50
54 ||  49 |  50
   ||  50 |  49
55 ||  48 |  50
   ||  49 |  49
   ||  50 |  48
56 ||  47 |  50
  etc.
```

For $x = 53$, there is only one combination of $y$ and $z$.
For $x = 54$, there are $2$.
For $x = 55$, there are $3$.
For $x = 56$, there will be $4$.
$\,\,\,$etc. All the way up to $x = 100$, which will have $48$.

Then we just sum up the numbers $1,2,3...48$ using $n(n+1)/2 = 1176$ total combinations to get a sum of $153$.

For a sum of $154$, then the min $x$ can be is $54$, and the cycle is intuitive.

Let's see the pattern with totals instead of $x$s now.

$T = 153$ means $S(n), n = 48$ --> $S = 1176$
$T = 154$ means $S(n), n = 47$ --> $S = 1128$ 
$T = 155$ means $S(n), n = 46$ --> $S = 1081$

There is a formula for the sum of the sum of the natural numbers!

So $S_2(n) = \frac{n}1\cdot\frac{n+1}2\cdot\frac{n+2}3$

$S_2(48) = \frac16\cdot48\cdot49\cdot50=$**$19600$**

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\rm N}{\rm .}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm solutions}\;{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  50 \le x' \le 100 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y,z \le 50 \hfill \cr 
  153 \le x' + y + z \le 200 \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm N}{\rm .}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm solutions}\;{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x,y,z \le 50 \hfill \cr 
  103 \le x + y + z \le 150 \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm N}{\rm .}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm solutions}\;{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a,b,c \le 50 \hfill \cr 
  103 \le \left( {50 - a} \right) + \left( {50 - b} \right) + \left( {50 - c} \right) \le 150 \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm N}{\rm .}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm solutions}\;{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a,b,c \le 50 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a + b + c \le 47 \le 50 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Since $47 \le 50$, you can omit the upper bound on the variables and reduce the problem to
$$
{\rm N}{\rm .}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm solutions}\;{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le a,b,c \hfill \cr 
  0 \le a + b + c \le 47 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
for which you can use stars and bars, or better [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $47$ into $3$ parts.

In general instead (if the upper bound was higher than $50$), you can use the formula
provided in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).