# How many solutions are there to the linear equation?

Tags: combinatorics

I have encountered problems asking me to calculate the total number of solutions to specific linear equations with specific constraints, but I want to know if there is a way to approach a more general problem. So the problem is:

Given this linear equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... + x_n = A$$
Find the total number of solutions such that all $x_i$s satisfy $0 \leq x_i < m$ and $x_i$s are integers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
This is the number of [Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $s$ *restricted* to $x_j \in \{0,1, \cdot,r\}$,
and the solution is given by
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
 }$$
You will find a comprehensive explanation [in this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).

The restricted **Partitions**  are instead the
$$
P_b (s,r,m) = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  { 1} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le r \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  \le x_{\,2}  \le \; \cdots \; \le x_{\,m}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake & providing an appropriate answer. I have deleted my answer as it's not correct. One small point is you made a fairly common misspelling of my surname in your answer.

Comment: I think it is better that you keep your answer, because it is in any case useful in case the $x_k$ were arranged in order: just specify that assumption. and sorry for misspelling your name

Comment: No worries re: misspelling my name. As for keeping my answer, I agree it might have some value as long as anybody reading it doesn't assume it properly answers the question. Thus, I have added an initial note to the answer to address this.

Comment: On further reflection, as my answer doesn't add anything to what the link to [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partitions_in_a_rectangle_and_Gaussian_binomial_coefficients) already provides, and you already mention about restricted partitions in your answer, I have deleted my answer again. This means I lose its $3$ up votes, but I'm not too concerned about the reputation loss plus I got it for something which wasn't really correct for answering the question.