# What is the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^{17}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I figured that $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{17} = (1-x^6)^{17}*(1-x)^{-17}$ but don't know what else to do.

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You can [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) each of those factors and then do [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), but with [reverse degree monomial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) to compute the first $6$  terms.

Comment: This feels like something that ought to have a stunning solution involving generating functions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is the generating function.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{%
\bracks{x^{5}}\pars{1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + x^{5}}^{17}} =
\bracks{x^{5}}\pars{1 - x^{6}}^{17}\pars{1 - x}^{-17}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{x^{5}}\pars{1 - x}^{-17} = {-17 \choose 5}\pars{-1}^{5} =
-\bracks{{-\pars{-17} + 5 - 1 \choose 5}\pars{-1}^{5}}
\\[5mm] = &\ {21 \choose 5} = \bbx{20349}
\end{align}

Comment: +1 nice use of binomial expansion on negative exponents

Comment: Why does $[x^5](1-x^6)^{17}(1-x)^{-17} = [x^5](1-x)^{-17}$? Thank you

Comment: @lambchopp $(1-x^6)^{17}=1-17x^6+\dots$, so the only way it contributes to the $x^5$ coefficient is from the constant term, hence $[x^5](1-x^6)^{17}(1-x)^{-17}=[x^5]1(1-x)^{-17}$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. And thanks for replying to $\texttt{@lambchopp}$ comment.

Comment: neat and quick (+1)

Comment: @GCab Thanks. Indeed, short.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\left( {1 + x + x^2  + x^3  + x^4 } \right)^{\,17}  = \left( {{{1 - x^5 } \over {1 - x}}} \right)^{\,17} 
$$
you might be interested to know that the general
case of what are somewhere called [*r-nomial coefficients*](http://oeis.org/A035343) corresponds to the O.G.F:
$$
F_b (x,r,m) = \sum\limits_{0\,\, \leqslant \,\,s\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\,r\,m} \right)} {N_b (s,r,m)\;x^{\,s} }
  = \left( {1 + x +  \cdots  + x^{\,r} } \right)^m  = \left( {\frac{{1 - x^{\,r + 1} }}{{1 - x}}} \right)^m 
$$
where
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$

You can find a full explanation [in this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) and in [this paper](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm)

In your particular case, if it is $(1+ \cdots+x^4)^{17}$
$$
\eqalign{
  & N_b (5,4,17)\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over {r + 1}}\, \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  17 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  21 - 5k \cr 
  5 - 5k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  17 \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  21 \cr 
  5 \cr}  \right) - \left( \matrix{
  17 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  16 \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  21 \cr 
  5 \cr}  \right) - 17 = 20322 \cr} 
$$
or for $(1+ \cdots+x^5)^{17}$
$$
\eqalign{
  & N_b (5,5,17)\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over {r + 1}}\, \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  17 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  5 + 17 - 1 - 6k \cr 
  5 - 6k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over {r + 1}}\, \le \,m} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  17 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  21 - 6k \cr 
  5 - 6k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  21 \cr 
  5 \cr}  \right) = 20349 \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can pick up an $x^5$ from one term and a $1$ from every other term 17 different ways.

You can pick up an $x^4$ from one term, an $x$ from a second term in $\dfrac{17!}{15!}$ ways.

You can get $x^3$ and $x^2$ in $\dfrac{17!}{15!}$ ways.

You can get $x^3$, $x$, $x$ in $\dfrac{17!}{1!2!14!}$ ways.

You can get $x^2, x^2, x$ in $\dfrac{17!}{1!2!14!}$ ways.

You can get $x^2,x,x,x$ in $\dfrac{17!}{1!3!13!}$ ways.

And finally, you can get $x,x,x,x,x$ in $\dbinom{17}{5}$ ways.

Show that this is exhaustive, and it should give you the correct answer.

Final tally:

$$17+2\cdot \dfrac{17!}{15!} + 2\cdot \dfrac{17!}{2!14!} + \dfrac{17!}{3!13!} + \dfrac{17!}{5!12!} = 20,349$$

Comment: Why is it $17!/15!$

Comment: You have an $x^4$ an $x$ and 15 $1$'s. So, the number of multiset permutations are $$\dfrac{17!}{1!1!15!} = \dfrac{17!}{15!}$$ I was a little lazy with my notation.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes. Your answer is right. The sum was a missprint.

Answer (score 1):

Another combinatorial approach:

When you multiply it out, each term is of the following form:

$$x^{a_1}x^{a_2}\cdots x^{a_{17}} = x^{a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_{17}}$$

You are looking for the number of solutions to $a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_{17} = 5$ where $\forall i: 0\le a_i \le 5$. Since the sum must add to 5 and there are no negatives, this is automatically satisfied, so we can ignore the upper bounds (a solution with no upper bounds is the same as a solution with upper bounds of 5 for each factor).

This is a well-known problem. It is the number of nonnegative integral solutions to a Diophantine equation. The solution is $$\dbinom{5+17-1}{5} = \dbinom{21}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to the problem: how many ways can $5$ candies be distributed among $17$ children? Mathematically, it is:
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{17}=5, 0\le x_i\le 5, i=1,2,...,17.$$
The partitions of $5$ are:
$$\begin{align}\{5\} &\Rightarrow P(17,1)=\frac{17!}{16!}=17\\
\{4,1\} &\Rightarrow P(17,2)=\frac{17!}{15!}=272\\
\{3,2\}&\Rightarrow P(17,2)=\frac{17!}{15!}=272\\
\{3,1,1\}&\Rightarrow \frac{P(17,3)}{2!}=\frac{17!}{2\cdot 14!}=2040\\
\{2,2,1\}&\Rightarrow \frac{P(17,3)}{2!}=\frac{17!}{2\cdot 14!}=2040\\
\{2,1,1,1\}&\Rightarrow \frac{P(17,4)}{3!}=\frac{17!}{6\cdot 13!}=9520\\
\{1,1,1,1,1\}&\Rightarrow \frac{P(17,5)}{5!}=\frac{17!}{120\cdot 12!}=6188\\
\end{align}$$
Hence, the sum is: $20,349$.