# A fair six-sided die is thrown n times. How to calculate certain probabilities of the sum S of these rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

To name these probabilities:

the sum S being less than a threshold N
the sum S being at least the threshold N
the sum S being exactly the threshold N
the sum being in a certain interval $[N_1,N_2] $

e.g. after 100 rolls less than 367, at least 342, exactly 350 and in $ [350,351]$?

How could I approach that?

Addendum: Could I valuably do that with a Monte-Carlo-simulation if the probabilities should only be in a certain range of precision?

I wrote a R-script for the Monte-Carlo and checked it with a "manual" calculation. We lnow that with independent variables the expected value and the variance are linear, therefor i can calculate that and get the standard deviation $\sigma$. With that and the PDF of the standard normal distribution, which we know is usable here because of Irwin Hall, i can calculate the percentage.

Does that make sense? Is there a more precise approach?

Comment: Monte Carlo is one way. You can also use the central limit theorem for a good approximation

Comment: do you have a good example on how that could be done?

Comment: See my answer bellow. I give an example for your first example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for
 $$ 
 \eqalign{ 
   & N(s,m) = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{ 
   {\rm 1} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le 6 \hfill \cr  
   x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr  
   &  = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{ 
   {\rm 0} \le {\rm integer}\;y_{\,j}  \le 5 \hfill \cr  
   y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + y_{\,m}  = s - m \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr  
   &  = N_b (s - m,5,m) \cr}  
 $$ 
where
 $$ 
 N_b (s,r,m) = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{ 
   {\rm 0} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le r \hfill \cr  
   x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right. 
 $$ 
and is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
as thoroughfully described in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).

Note that the Cumulative Number of solutions for $s$ up to $S$ is given by
 $$ 
 \eqalign{ 
   & M_b (S,r,m) = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{ 
   {\rm 0} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le r \hfill \cr  
   x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \; \cdots \; + x_{\,m}  \le S \hfill \cr}  \right. =   \cr  
   &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\, \le \,S\,} {N_b (s,r,m)} \quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over {r + 1}}\, \le \,m} \right)} 
  {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{ 
   m \hfill \cr  
   k \hfill \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ 
   S + m - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr  
   S - k\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}  \cr}  
 $$ 
which answers to your questions about getting  "no less than ..."  or "between $S_1$ and $S_2$".

We have that 
 $$ 
 \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,s\,\,\left( { \le \,r\,m} \right)\,} {N_b (s,r,m)}  
 $$ 
and therefore
 $$ 
 P_b (s,r,m) = {{N_b (s,r,m)} \over {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m} }} 
$$
is the probability distribution of the sum $s$ of $m$ i.i.d. *discrete* variables, with support $[0,r]$.

For large values of throws ($m$), the Probability tends to the probability distribution of the
sum of $m$ *continuous* random variables uniformly distributed on $[-1/2,r+1/2]$, which is
known as [Irwin Hall Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution),  and which in turn becomes asymptotic to a normal distribution
 with mean and variance equal to $m$ times the mean and variance of the uniform random variable on $[-1/2,r+1/2]$, i.e.
 $$ 
 \eqalign{ 
   & P_{\,b} (s,r,m) = {{N_{\,b} (s,r,m)} \over {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m} }} \approx   \cr  
  &  \approx {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi m\sigma ^{\,2} } }}e^{\, - \,{{\left( {s - m\mu } \right)^{\,2} } \over {2m\sigma ^{\,2} }}}
  = {{\sqrt {6/\pi } } \over {\sqrt {m\left( {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,2} } \right)} }}e^{\, - \,6{{\left( {s - mr/2} \right)^{\,2} } \over {m\left( {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,2} } \right)}}}  \cr} 
$$

Comment: still digesting this :) thank you. and it kinda answered it even if i took a different approach, but the hint with e irwin-hall-distribution was very useful for that. do you think there would be a another approach over the density function?

Comment: @vik I had the chance to study this subject quite in depth, and  I summarized above the capital points. The problem pops up in different disciplines, discrete geometry, diophantine equations, random walks and Markov chains, etc., and so there are various approaches, but end results are of course those summarized above. Should you need  more information on a particular aspect, let me know.

Comment: @vik I have expanded a bit the "asymptotics" section to make more explicit the passage *discrete variables" $\;\to \;$ "continuous  variables" $\;\to \;$ "normal variables"

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exact answer but an approximation using Central Limit Theorem

First we need to find $E(X)$ and $VAR(X)$ where $X$ is a random variable with Probability Mass Function:

$P(X=i)=1/6,$ $for$ $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$

So we have:

$E(X)=\frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5+6)=\frac{21}{6}=\frac{7}{2}$

$E(X^2)=\frac{1}{6}(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2)=\frac{91}{6}$

$VAR(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=\frac{91}{6}-\frac{49}{4}=\frac{35}{12}$

We will use Central Limit Theorem to calculate the probability of the sum of 100 rolls being less than 367.(Your first example that is)

$$P(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i < 367)\simeq P(\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i \leq 367.5)=P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i-100*E(X)}{\sqrt{100*VAR(X)}} \leq \frac{367.5-100*E(X)}{\sqrt{100*VAR(X)}}) \simeq \Phi(\frac{367.5-100*E(X)}{\sqrt{100*VAR(X)}}) \simeq \Phi(1.0247) \simeq 0.847$$

You can work in a similar way to calculate the probability of the sum of $n$ rolls being greater than a certain number $A$ or between certain numbers $A$ and $B$. As for the $\Phi$ table you can find it easily on the internet. If you have any questions about how to use the Theorem for other similar problems ask in the comments

Comment: thanks a lot, that, too, helped tremendously. as i keep saying: i am quite new to this all :)