# If I roll a dice 4 times then what is the probability of getting 20 total dots?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So, here the total evets = $6^4$

If I get $a,b,c,d$ doing each rolling then, $$a+b+c+d=20$$
$$where\ a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N} \ and\ 1\le a,b,c,d\le6$$

Now, how can I solve this by **stars and bars** method? Or there are other easier ways to solve this?

Comment: Principle of inclusion and exclusion and complementary counting

Comment: See https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm.

Answer (score 4):

Write out all the ways you can get 20 dots total with 4 dice (there should be 5 up to reordering if I didn't miscount). Then compute the chance for each of these events. Here you need to keep track of the different ways to arrange the dots. For example there are 4 events for getting 6,6,6,2 because each of the 4 dice can be the one with the 2.

Comment: This is too cumbersome. Brute force is not desirable!!

Answer (score 4):

Using generating functions: The number of ways to roll a total of $20$ on four dice is $$\begin{align}[x^{20}](x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^4 &= [x^{16}](1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^4 \\ &= [x^{16}]\left({1-x^6 \over 1-x}\right)^4 \\ 
&= [x^{16}]{\binom40-\binom41x^6+\binom42x^{12}-\cdots \over (1-x)^4} \\
&= [x^{16}]{\binom40 \over (1-x)^4}-[x^{10}]{\binom41 \over (1-x)^4}+[x^4]{\binom42 \over (1-x)^4} \\
&= \binom40\binom{19}3-\binom41\binom{13}3+\binom42\binom{7}3 \\ &= 35. \end{align}$$ The probability is therefore $\frac{35}{6^4} = \frac{35}{1296} \approx 2.7\%$.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for:
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm 1} \le {\rm integer}\;x_{\,j}  \le 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + \;x_{\,3} \; + x_{\,4}  = 20 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = {\rm No}{\rm .}\,{\rm of}\,{\rm solutions}\,{\rm to}\;\left\{ \matrix{
  {\rm 0} \le {\rm integer}\;y_{\,j}  \le 5 \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + \;y_{\,3} \; + y_{\,4}  = 16 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
and because $5<16$ you cannot apply "stars and bars" directly.

The general solution to
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
as explained in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420),
and which is a better way to write the formula already presented by @satishramanathan 
because it renders superfluous the summation bounds, as being implicit in the binomial.

That said, in your case there is a nice shortcut, using the fact that $N_b (s,r,m)=N_b (m \cdot r -s,r,m)$
as can be easily verified.
That is, you can ask that the sum of the "missing points" be four, in which case you can apply 
"stars and bars" or [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $4$ into four parts, and get
$$
N = \binom{4+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{7}{3}=35
$$
which, of course would be the same if you computed 
$N_b (m \cdot r -s,r,m)= N_b (4,5,4)$, because the sum reduces to the only term in $k=0$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the formula for finding the distribution of sum $s$ in throwing $n$ dice with $x$ sides goes like this

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor\frac{(s-n)}{x}\rfloor} (-1)^k {n\choose k}{(s-1-xk)\choose (n-1)}$$

Thus in your case, the favorable cases would be

$ = (-1)^0 {4\choose0}{19\choose3}+(-1)^1 {4\choose1}{13\choose3}+(-1)^2 {4\choose2}{7\choose3}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your formula uses the exact same brute force as my solution. The only difference is that I spelled out where the formula comes from whereas in your case you just cite a ready made formula and plug in numbers.

Comment: Thanks for correcting!!.

Comment: You should write $(-1)^k$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig.  It is better now, you are right.