# In how many ways we could divide 300 same balls into three boxes so in each box not will be more than 180 balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways we could divide 300 same balls into 3 boxes so in each box will not be more than 180 balls.

Is it correct if I want to sum all the options with $n+k+1\choose n-1$ and subtract all the "bad" options?

so we have $n+k+1\choose n-1$=$300+3-1\choose 300-1$
and we need to subtract "bad" options (how to calculate them?)

What the right way to do it?

Comment: Use Inclusion/Exclusion. If you put 121 balls into a single box, then distribute the remaining $300-121=179$ balls, how many ways are there? If you put 121 balls into two different boxes, that leaves $179-121=58$ balls to distribute. Is it possible to have over 120 balls in all three boxes?

Comment: Also, you are swapping the $n$ and the $k$. It should be $$\dbinom{3+300-1}{3-1}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, In my notebook is written the above formula. 
here n=3 and k=300?

Comment: That is correct. $n=3,k=300$. Rather than memorizing formulas, it may be easier to memorize a methodology for counting. This is the [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

Comment: Also, you have a typo: $$\dbinom{n+k\color{red}{+}1}{n-1} \text{ should be } \dbinom{n+k\color{red}{-}1}{n-1}$$ Here you have $k$ balls being placed into $n$ bins.

Comment: An update to my comment about Inclusion/Exclusion, when I first read the problem, you were asking that the upper bound of balls in boxes be 120. Now that it is 180, it is not possible to have two balls violate the upper bound at the same time.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: stars and bars here does not work: the bars should be kept at a distance $\le 180$ !

Comment: @JohnD: are the boxes distinguishable or undistinguishable ?

Comment: @GCab the boxes are distinguishable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad option means, you have put $181$ balls somewhere, therefore "remove" these balls from consideration and distribute all the rest in all possible ways -- it should give you the number of "bad options" divided by three (number of ways to put 181 ball somewhere).

For test let's consider the problem with smaller numbers.
Say you want to distribute $3$ balls to $3$ boxes so that no box contains more than $1$ ball.
Obviously, there is only one way to do that.
Now consider how do we get this number.
The total number of distributions is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 + 3 - 1 \\ 3 - 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
10.
$$
Now consider bad options.
There are two balls in one of the boxes, the remaining balls can be distributed
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 + 3 - 1 \\ 3 - 1
\end{pmatrix} = 3
$$
different ways (quite obvious since I have $3$ boxes and I can put the remaining ball anywhere).
Since the "removed" two balls can be in any box, the total number of bad options is
$$
3 \times 3 = 9.
$$
Thus the number of good options is
$$
10 - 9 = 1.
$$

**UPD.** Seems my answer caused some controversy, thus I add calculations for the mentioned case.
The total number of all possible distributions is
$$
t = \begin{pmatrix} 300+3-1\\3-1 \end{pmatrix} = 45451.
$$
On the other hand, number of bad distributions is
$$
b = 3 \begin{pmatrix} (300 - 181) + 3 - 1\\ 3 - 1 \end{pmatrix} = 21780.
$$
Thus the result
$$
t - b = 23671.
$$

Comment: does not work in this way : refer to my answer and the post linked there.

Comment: It yields 23671, same result as your method does. total = $\begin{pmatrix} 300+3-1\\3-1 \end{pmatrix}=45451$, while bad = $3 \begin{pmatrix} (300 - 181) + 3 - 1\\ 3 - 1 \end{pmatrix}=21780$. Difference is total-bad = $23671$

Comment: ok, sorry for the misunderstanding: you are practically applying the inclusion-exclusion (the general formula in my answer) for $m=3$ and $s/(r+1) <2$ (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It is concept of multinomial
Number Of ways will be number of nonnegative integral solutions of equation a+b+c =300 where 0<= a,b,c <= 180.
Solutions are coffecient of x^300 in the expansion of ( 1 + x  + x^2 +..........x^180 )^3
i.e coffecient of x^300 in ((1-x^181)/(1-x))^3
i.e coffecient of x^ 300 in (1-x^181)^3 . (1-x)^-3
   =. (302*301)/2 - 3(121*120)/2
   = 23671

Comment: right, the multinomial expansion is a possible approach (although heavy).(+1)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
in your case with $s=300, \; r=180, \; m=3$

Now, $N_b$ is given by

$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
 as thoroughly explained [in this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420)

You get $N_b(300,\, 180, \, 3)=23671$

This if the balls are un-distinguishable and the boxes are **distinguishable**