# 1. You roll five fair, six-sided dice. What is the probability that the sum of the five dice is 20?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know we can try and count the number of ways that they can add to 20, however this is much easier when there is only 2 or 3 dice. I believe there is a way to do this using combinations but I am not sure. I thought it was a stars and bars, so I wrote out 
20 like ->
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 |+ 1 + 1 + 1 + 1| + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 |+ 1 + 1 + 1 |+ 1 + 1 + 1

Which makes a 20 choose 4, however, this is over counting as each block of 1's can't be greater than 6 or less than 1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't mind using computer assistance... it would be the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{6^5}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5$

Comment: @JMoravitz That works, Can you explain a little why that is correct? I am shocked that got the same answer. Thanks!

Comment: Let us use some colors and make the example smaller... imagine we roll a three sided die instead three times... $(x+x^2+x^3)^3 = \color{red}{(x+x^2+x^3)}\color{blue}{(x+x^2+x^3)}\color{green}{(x+x^2+x^3)}$ after foiling *and without simplifying* will look like $\color{red}{x}\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{x}+\color{red}{x^2}\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{x}+\color{red}{x}\color{blue}{x^2}\color{green}{x}+\dots+\color{red}{x^3}\color{blue}{x^3}\color{green}{x^3}$.  Each term in the expansion before simplification refers to a specific sequence of die rolls.

Comment: Each of these outcomes in the pre-simplified pre-aggregated expansion are equally likely to have occurred and there are $3^3=27$ of them in that example (*or more generally $k^n$ of them for a $k$-sided die being rolled $n$ times*).  After having simplified and aggregated the terms, the coefficients there are the number of ways of having rolled a total of that amount having "forgotten" which numbers actually appeared and in what order.  Dividing by $k^n$ then gives the probability of having achieved that sum.

Comment: have a look at this [related post][http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420]

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without a computer. As explained by others, and in the linked question, the generating function of your problem is given by
$$\eqalign{
g(x)&=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5 \cr
&=x^5\left({1-x^6\over 1-x}\right)^5=x^5(1-x^6)^5(1-x)^{-5}\cr
&=x^5\ (1-5x^6+10x^{12}+{\rm higher\ terms})\ \sum_{j=0}^\infty{5+j-1\choose j}x^j\ .\cr}$$
Now you have to find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ on the RHS. This coefficient is
$${19\choose15}-5{13\choose9}+10{7\choose3}=651\ .$$
This is the number of lucky outcomes among the $6^5$ possible, and equally probable, histories.

Comment: There is a "-?" there, what is it supposed to be?

Comment: @HellSaint: It collects the terms in $(1-x^6)^5$ that have no effect in our problem, since their degrees are too large.

Comment: I am confused on how you got the coefficient for the x^5 term. I guess I am mostly confused on how you got j and also the first step when you get 1-x^6)/(1-x), could you explain this?

Comment: @SamCole: $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^5$ is a finite geometric series with a summation formula. $(1-x)^{-5}$ is computed with the binomial series.