# What is the probability that the maximum number of ping-pong balls in any bowl is exactly 3?

Tags: probability

We randomly put 8 indistinguishable ping-pong balls in 5 bowls, where each bowl can hold any number of ping-pong balls. What is the probability that the maximum number of ping-pong balls in any bowl is exactly 3?

You may assume that the 5 bowls are distinguishable. How can i use bars and stars method to solve this?

Comment: I would first consider the case where $\color{green}7$  indistinguishable ping-pong balls are put in $5$ bowls.

Comment: Stars and Bars is not easily applied to questions like this.  For instance, if you have $2$ balls and $2$ bowls, Stars and Bars gives three arrangements, namely $(1,1), (2,0), (0,2)$ but the probability that the max in a bow is $2$ is equal to $\frac 12$ (clearly).

Comment: $5^8$ total arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

To have a maximum of $3$ balls in one bowl they must be distributed $3+3+2+0+0,\ 3+3+1+1+0,\ 3+2+2+1+0, \text {or } 3+2+1+1+1$.  I don't think you can use stars and bars because not all distributions have the same probability.  The number of ways to get $3+3+2+0+0$ is the product of

${5 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the bowls with $3$ balls
$3$ ways to choose the bowl with $2$ balls
$8 \choose 3$ ways to choose the $3$ balls in the fist bowl
$5 \choose 3$ ways to choose the $3$ balls in the second bowl
so the chance is 
$$\frac {{5 \choose 2}3{8\choose 3}{5 \choose 3}}{5^8}=\frac {10\cdot 3 \cdot 56 \cdot 10}{5^8}=\frac{672}{15625}$$

Now do the same for each other distribution and add them up.

Comment: first * just so you know.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: I don't understand the comment

Comment: typo correction.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake from my part

Answer (score 0):

An important premise first of all.

Specifying that the bins are distinguishable and the balls are not is *not sufficient*.

As a matter of fact the sentence
"(uniformly) randomly **put** $s$ un-distinguishable balls into $m$ distinguishable bins"
commonly has two different interpretations, which differ as for what concerns the *space of equi-probable events* being considered, that is

a) to **launch** the balls into the bins
in this case we consider that for each ball we have $m$ equiprobable choices for where it is going to land, and therefore that our space
is given by the events (ball $j$, bin $k$), which are in total
$$m^s$$.

b) to **lay** (distribute, deposit, pour, ..) the balls into the bins
in which case we are considering as equiprobable result each of the possible "occupancy histogram" made up of $m$ bars 
of height $h_k$, with the heights summing up to $s$;
the number of histograms is the same as that of the [(weak) compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $s$ into $m$ parts, or [stars & bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) analogy
which is
$$ \binom{s+m-1}{s}$$

So, assuming that you are referring to the interpretation b) by citing the stars and bars method, consider that the number of
weak compositions of $s$ into $m$ parts with each part being *at most* $r$, that is
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
is given by
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
as thoughly explained [in this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).

Thus the answer to your particular case is 
$$
N = N_b (8,3,5) - N_b (8,2,5) = 155 - 15 = 140
$$