# How many possibilities are there to split a number $N$ in a sum of $n$ numbers from 0 to 9?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine we have given some natural number $N$ and some natural number $n$.

How many possibilities are there to have numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in \{0, \ldots, 9\} $ such that

$$x_1+ \ldots+ x_n=N$$

In this case the sorting matters, so $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ count as two possibilities

Also numbers can appear twice so it is possible that $x_i=x_j$

Comment: can you include what you have tried so far? This will make people think you really need help, and you are not just posting whatever comes into your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Changing $N$ to $s$, $n$ to $m$ and $9$ to $r$, that means to find
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

As explained in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) that is computed as
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$