# What is the distribution function for the sum of N discrete variables [0,1,2]

Tags: combinatorics, summation, integer-partitions

say I have N discrete variables.  The first variable has to be 2. The second variable can either be 1 or 2, but not 0. The remaining can either be 0,1 or 2.

What is the distribution of the sum of these variables? Can it be explicitly expressed?

i.e Given some number Y, How many ways are there for the N variables to sum to Y?

- As stated in the comments, lets assume the variables are independent and  uniform

Comment: You have to assume independence of the variables. Otherwise the distribution function of the sum cannot be determined. Besides, it is not clear if you are assuming that the variables have uniform distribution on their ranges.

Comment: Take the $N-2$ discrete variables that are ${\cal U}[0,2]$.  Their sum is a binomial with mean $(N-2)$, and variance given by formulas.  Now add the single variable that is a constant $2$.  This simply shifts the mean of binomial to $(N-2)+2 = N$, with the same variance.  The only tricky part is now adding on a binomial ${\cal B}(1, 1/2)$ which leads to a binomial with mean $N + 3/2$, where the variance is calculated by the sum of variance formula....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's disregard the first two variables, which can be easily managed out of the sum, and let's answer
to the question 
*which is the number of [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $S-3$  (or $S-4$) into $N-2$ parts, restricted to be in $\{0,1,2 \}$ ?*

Well, in the general case in which we are looking for 
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
the **exact answer** is given by the finite sum

$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
as explained in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420).

If you are looking for asymptotic approximations for large $s$ and $m$, then you can
approximate the discrete variable with a uniform continuos variable ranging on $[-1/2, r+1/2]$,
thus with mean $r/2$ and variance $(r+1)^2/12$.
The sum of $m$ uniform independent variables as above quickly approach the normal distribution
$$
\eqalign{
  & p_{\,b} (s;r,m) = {{N_{\,b} (s,r,m)} \over {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,m} }} \approx {1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi m\sigma ^{\,2} } }}e^{\, - \,{{\left( {s - m\mu } \right)^{\,2} } \over {2m\sigma ^{\,2} }}}   \cr 
  &  = {{\sqrt {6/\pi } } \over {\sqrt {m\left( {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,2} } \right)} }}e^{\, - \,6{{\left( {s - mr/2} \right)^{\,2} } \over {m\left( {\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,2} } \right)}}}  \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, there’s not enough information to answer the question about the distribution. To find the number of ways that the $N$ variables can sum to $Y$, denote the second variable by $x_2$ and the numbers of remaining variables that are $j$ by $a_j$ and write

\begin{eqnarray}
2+x_2+0a_0+1a_1+2a_2&=&Y\;,\\
1+1+a_0+a_1+a_2&=&N\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Now you can express $a_0$ and $a_1$ in terms of $a_2$ and $x_2$:

\begin{eqnarray}
a_0&=&N-Y+a_2+x_2\;,\\
a_1&=&Y-2-2a_2-x_2\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus the count is

$$
\sum_{x_2=1}^2\sum_{a_2=\max(0,Y-N-x_2)}^{\left\lfloor\frac{Y-2-x_2}2\right\rfloor}\binom{N-2}{N-Y+a_2+x_2,Y-2-2a_2-x_2,a_2}\\=\sum_{x_2=1}^2\sum_{a_2=\max(0,Y-N-x_2)}^{\left\lfloor\frac{Y-2-x_2}2\right\rfloor}\frac{(N-2)!}{(N-Y+a_2+x_2)!(Y-2-2a_2-x_2)!a_2!}\;.
$$

Comment: How did you get the  formula for the count? Im having difficulty following

Comment: @AbelTan: The number of ways to select $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ from $N-2$ variables, summed over all possible values of $x_2$ and $a_2$.

Comment: @AbelTan: I just realized that one of the lower incides could get negative; I've adjusted the lower bound of the second sum accordingly to ensure that all three lower indices are non-negative.

Comment: How did you derive formula after the "the count is"?  Perhaps you can explain how the formula counts the number of ways to select

Comment: @AbelTan: Perhaps I don't understand the question. I thought I'd answered it in my previous comment. Do you know how to count the ways to select groups of $i$, $j$ and $k$ elements from $n$ elements?

Comment: No i dont.  I just know the standard nCr formula to select r elements from a set of n. Is this i,j,k thing a more advanced extension of this concept?

Comment: @AbelTan: I see. It is. There are $\binom nr=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ ways to choose $r$ from $n$ elements because you can arrange the $n$ elements in $n!$ ways and take the first $r$, but $r!$ permutations of the $r$ elements and $(n-r)!$ permutations of the remaining $n-r$ elements will lead to the same result, so we have to divide by those factors. The same for three groups: Arrange the $n$ elements in $n!$ ways and form the three groups from the first $i$, the next $j$ and the remaining $k$ elements, and compensate for the invariance under $i!$, $j!$ and $k!$ permutations.

Comment: Thank you jokiri. Might i know what is the name of this formula so that i can read up on it?

Comment: @AbelTan: These are [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104303/discussion-between-abel-tan-and-joriki).