# Need help with his advance dice probability scenario(concept)

Tags: probability, dice

So the question goes-

- Mr.Bhallu rolls $3$ standard $6$ sided fair dice together.
- He wins if the total sum of the outcomes after rerolling once is $7$.
- Mr.Bhallu can choose to reroll any number of dice
  $\left(0-3\right)$.
- He always plays to maximize his chances of winning, calculate the probabilty of him rerolling $2$ dices.

Can someone please explain the concept(s) at use here along with probability for choosing to reroll each ( no dice ), ( $1$ dice) and ( $3$ dice ) as well $?$.

Comment: You have to make a list of the possibilities, and calculate the probability that he wins.  He can re-roll all three dice, or he can have a total of $1$ through $6$ and re-roll two dice, or a total of $2$ through $6$ and roll  $1$ die.  Once you know those probabilities, you can figure out what's best to do for any of the original rolls.

Comment: Devansh: You have some answers that interpret the question in a couple of different ways.  Please look at them and clarify which interpretation you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the rules of the play as follows:
a) you roll three dice a first time: if you get a sum of $7$ you win, if you get more you loose, if you get less you can proceed with step b) ;
b) you are allowed to re-roll $1$ or $2$ or $3$ dice, deciding in advance how many, to try and complement to $7$ the sum previously obtained;
c) the decision in b) is taken as to optimize the probability of getting the needed complement.

Now, the probability of getting a sum $s$ when throwing $m$ dice is given by
$$
\eqalign{
  & p(s,m) = {{N_b (s - m,5,m)} \over {6^{\,m} }}\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers  }m \le s} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {6^{\,m} }}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \le \,{{s - m} \over 6}\, \le \,m} \right)}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{  m \hfill \cr   k \hfill \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  s - 1 - k6 \cr   s - m - k6 \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$
as explained [in this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420)

When you tabulate this for the case of interest you get

[image: 3dice_reroll_1]

and it is clear that if you do not get $7$ at the first instance, then you have better just to reroll only one dice.

In fact you have :

- $\approx 0.07$ to center $7$ with the first three dice;
- $\approx 0.05$ to get $6$ with the first three dice, then to get the missing $1$ the best and only way is to roll one die ;
- $\approx 0.03$ to get $5$ with the first three dice, then to get the missing $2$ the best way is to roll one die ;
- ....

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question?  If one rolls (say) $17$ with three dice, it surely cannot be optimal to re-roll only one die.  The lowest one can get with a single re-roll would be $12$.

Comment: @BrianTung: I added on top of the answer my understanding of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I don't understand the problem correctly, because I get a different answer from the one provided by G Cab.  Here's how I understand it: The player rolls three ordinary fair six-sided dice.  If the total is $7$, they stop (or equivalently, they re-roll zero dice).  This happens with probability $5/72$.

Otherwise, they are allowed to re-roll any number of dice: one, two, or three.  They are assumed to select optimally.  We want to find the probability that their choice is to re-roll two dice.

---

With that understanding, let us consider strategy.  The probability of winning when re-rolling three dice is the probability of rolling a $7$ on those three dice: again, $5/72$.  That will always be an option.

Re-rolling a single die is an option when the lowest two dice total no more than $6$.  Under those circumstances, the probability of winning is $1/6$, because exactly one result on the re-rolled die will work.  Note that $1/6 > 5/72$, so we always prefer to re-roll one die rather than three, when one is an option.

What about re-rolling two dice?  This is an option whenever the lowest die is no more than $5$.  However, if the lowest die is $5$, the probability of winning when re-rolling the two other dice is the probability of getting a $2$ on two dice: $1/36$.  This is lower than $5/72$.  Likewise, if the lowest die is $4$, the probability of winning when re-rolling the two other dice is the probability of getting a $3$ on two dice: $1/18$.  This again is lower than $5/72$.  Only when the lowest die is no more than a $3$ is it better to re-roll two dice than three.

How does re-rolling two dice compare to re-rolling one?  The easiest win when re-rolling two dice is when the lowest die is a $1$.  Then the probability of winning is that of getting a $6$ on two dice: $5/36$.  This is better than with three dice ($5/72$), but worse than with one die ($1/6$).  Therefore, we always prefer to re-roll one die when that is an option.

So here's our strategy:

1. If the lowest two dice sum up to no more than $6$, then re-roll the other die.
2. Else, if the lowest die is no more than $3$, then re-roll the other two dice.
3. Else, re-roll all three dice.

---

To find out the desired probability, therefore, enumerate those cases where the lowest two dice sum up to more than $6$, but where the lowest die is no more than $3$.  There are not that many cases.  Be sure to account carefully for all of the permutations.  For example, there are three permutations of a single $1$ and a pair of $6$s, but there are six permutations of a $2$, a $5$ and a $6$.  Count up all of the cases and divide by $6^3 = 216$, and there's your probability.

Comment: the difference with my understanding, is that by re-rolling a certain die you mean to delete the contribution of that die (which one ?) in the previous sum, while I understand that it is retained.

Comment: @GCab: Ahh, I see.  Well maybe we'll have to ask OP to clarify.

Comment: yes, indeed, that should be clarified

Answer (score 0):

I only reroll no dice if the sum is $7$ already.  The chance of getting $7$ on a roll of all three dice is $\frac 5{72}$ so I need something better to reroll $1$ or $2$ dice.  If I have two dice that sum to less than $7$, I can reroll the other and get a probability of $\frac 16$.  This is better than $\frac 5{72}$, so if I have two that sum to less than $7$ I don't reroll all three.

If I have a $1$ I can reroll the other two and have a chance of $\frac 5{36}$ to win.  This is the best case and is still less than $\frac 16$, so if I can reroll just one it dominates over rerolling two.  If I have a $2$ I can reroll the other two and have a chance of $\frac 4{36}$ and if I have a $3$ I can reroll the other two and have a chance of $\frac 3{36}$.  Both of these beat rerolling all three.  All of these are less than $\frac 16$, so we have a nice algorithm:

If the dice sum to $7$, stop here.
ElseIf the two lowest dice sum to less than $7$, reroll the other one.
ElseIf the lowest die is $3$ or less, keep it and reroll the other two.
Else, reroll all three.

Compute the probability of each line, and you want the chance of the second.

Comment: We came to the same conclusion. :-)