# If $12$ distinct balls are to be placed in $3$ identical boxes, then what's the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly $3$, balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

This is a bonus question asked in a competitive examination. It all choice are wrong.

I will put the question, then the solution I got from the internet and then my solution.

Please help to figure out whether my solution is correct or not.

[image]

The Answer of the website is as follow and I presume that it is wrong

[image]

My solution is as follow

[image]

Please help me with finding the correct solution if my solution is wrong.

Comment: The denominator of the answer should divide $3^{12}$ as $12$ balls are going into $3$ boxes.  Your solution does not

Comment: There does, at the very least, seem to be some inclusion-exclusion missing from the website's solution. Also, the answer to this question is entirely unaffected by whether the balls and boxes are distinguishable, so why specify that the balls are and the boxes aren't?

Comment: My $3^{12}$ refer to the case without restriction when both balls and boxes are distinct. Here Boxes are identical and balls are distict

Comment: I believe, $n(S)=3^{12}$ in website solutions is not correct if the boxes are identical.

Comment: YES , I will again repeat this is a BONUS question asked in a competitive examination

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-identical-bins/#:~:text=Distinct%20objects%20into%20identical%20bins%20is%20a%20problem,it%20does%20matter%20which%20objects%20are%20grouped%20together

Comment: Refer to this website for anyone who wants to solve it

Comment: Name the boxes as $a,b,c$ and let $A$ denote the event that box $a$ receives $3$ balls (same for $B$ and $C$). Then applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find answer: $$P(A\cup B\cup C)=3P(A)-3P(A\cap B)$$(note that $A\cap B\cap C=\varnothing$). The website gives wrongly $3P(A)$ as solution.

Comment: See my comment following the answer of Blaise.  See also [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: I found the probabilty $0.142...$ , but it is not in selections

Comment: What does being a "BONUS question" have to do with the answers being right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all the answers are wrong.

Your mistake lies towards the final step.

Distributions which have exactly one box having exactly $3$ balls is $29,920$ and if this is the intent, *this* should be the numerator.

Else if $3-3-9$ cases are also to be considered, you need to add only *half* of $18,480$

Thus final answer should either be $\dfrac{29920}{88574}\;\; or\;\;  \dfrac{39160}{88574}$

**Added material for $3$ ball cases**

$\displaylines{9-3-0:\frac{12!}{9!3!} = 220\\ 8-3-1:\frac{12!}{8!3!1!}=1980\\6-3-3: \frac{12!}{6!3!3!}\Big/2! = 9240\\5-4-3: \frac{12!}{5!4!3!} = 27720}$

Total if exactly one box has to have exactly $3$ balls $= 29,920$

Total if one or more boxes can have exactly $3$ balls $=39,160$

Comment: Let's take example of $4$ different balls and $3$ identical urns. What would you say the probability of at least one of the urns having exactly $2$ balls is? $9/14$?

Comment: @Samar Imam Zaidi: The consensus of seasoned experts is that when **probability** is being asked for, the information re the boxes being identical is irrelevant. So you could untick my answer and tick another with the solution treating it as distinct balls in distinct boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Whether the urns are identical or distinct does not change the probability that one of the boxes has exactly $3$ balls.

Applying the principle of inclusion exclusion, number of ways of distributing $12$ balls in three urns such that at least one of the urns has exactly $3$ balls is

$\displaystyle {3 \choose 1} {12 \choose 3} \cdot 2^9 - {3 \choose 2} {12 \choose 3} {9 \choose 3}$

We first choose an urn that will receive $3$ balls and choose $3$ balls for the urn and then distribute rest $9$ balls in remaining $2$ urns. But each of them will also count cases where two of the urns have $3$ balls each. So in total, cases where two urns receive $3$ balls each is overcounted once and hence we subtract those using the next term.

The question does not state clearly but if the distribution must have balls in each of the three urns then the number of ways is,

$\displaystyle {3 \choose 1} {12 \choose 3} \cdot (2^9 - 2) - {3 \choose 2} {12 \choose 3} {9 \choose 3}$

I take out two cases from $2^9$ where one of the remaining urns received remaining all $9$ balls.

Finally, dividing by $3^{12}$ gives the desired probability.

Comment: you gave very important details ! +1

Comment: @Bulbasaur thank you.

Comment: i  want to ask something different , when we  think the denominator part is a different combinatorics question such that dispersing $12$ different balls into $3$ identical urn , then the OP's answer is a good way , it is 88574 .however , if we want to solve it by exponential generating functions , then it would be $(3^{12})/3!=88573.5)$. what is the mistake here?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129910/bulbasaur

Comment: @Math Lover: I respectfully disagree with your answer. The denominator I get is $88574$ which has prime factors $2\times 67\times 661$. This question may also be seen in this context. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256025/arranging-books-in-bookshelves-with-the-capacity-of-each-shelf-given/4256253#4256253

Comment: @trueblueanil $88574$ would be the right answer if you were looking for number of ways to distribute $12$ different balls to $3$ _identical_ urns. That is $ [3^{12} - 3] / 3! + 1 = 88574$ but this is a question on probability. Regardless of whether I marked the urns differently vs. I left them unmarked, the probability of an urn receiving _exactly_ $3$ balls does not change.

Comment: Sorry, but the question *clearly* mentions identical boxes, and OP has added up configurations of only $1$ box full, $2$ boxes filled and $3$ boxes full. I'll presently post arrangements with boxes having exactly $3$ balls, it's not tedious to compute for such a small problem, but I'm not getting a general formula.

Comment: Yes OP has clearly mentioned identical boxes but this is a question on probability and not combinatorics. The method OP chooses will not give the correct probability for the same reason that stars and bars does not given correct probability in most cases. The outcomes you count in OP's method may not be equi-probable.

Comment: The point that I am making is that let's take $3$ identical urns first and then later say I put a different color mark on each of them. Would that change the probability that at least one of the urns receives exactly $3$ balls? The method that I use ensures that all outcomes are equi-probable.

Comment: After more thought, I'm confused ! My question is: How are boxes filled to give Stirling numbers ? I'm not so sure that you are wrong, I'll change my vote ! :-)

Comment: @trueblueanil I know very little about downvoting an answer because I have never used it for an answer from a reputed user :)

Comment: Done ! plus one

Answer (score 0):

The probability is equivalent to the sum of the probabilites that any urn gets 3 balls, that is, "3 balls go in urn 1 and 9 go in the other two" + "3 balls go in urn 2 and 9 go in the other two" + "3 balls get in urn 3 and 9 go in the other two".
You can compute these probabilites by just assigning urn numbers to each ball one by one. You'd find that the probability is 1/3^3 * 2/3^9 * 12 C 3, multiplied by 3 for each of the urn gives an exact 112640/177147, which is the same result as given by the website

Comment: This is a bonus question, hence all the answers are wrong. Boxes are identical so no urn 1 , urn 2 and urn 3

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi You can make the boxes distinguishable if you want. The probability is unaffected by taking a marker and writing numbers on the boxes.

Comment: Though the website solved it , it is still a BONUS question and no body solved it correctly, hence I need help

Comment: Look at my solution and combare it with the following website solution

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-identical-bins/#:~:text=Distinct%20objects%20into%20identical%20bins%20is%20a%20problem,it%20does%20matter%20which%20objects%20are%20grouped%20together

Comment: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1292214964

Comment: Put n=12, hence S(12,1)+S(12,2)+S(12,3) is the total number of cases

Comment: This is not correct because solutions are counted more than once. E.g. solution $(3,3,6)$ is counted twice.

Comment: Per the comment of @drhab, while the problem is a nice fit for Inclusion-Exclusion, the problem can be attacked in other ways.  Inclusion-Exclusion is simply the easiest.  Let $|S|$ denote the # of elements in the finite set $S$.  Given finite sets $A_1, \cdots, A_n$, define $$T_r = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq n} \left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_r}\right|.$$  That is, $T_r$ is computed via consideration of $\binom{n}{r}$ terms, where each term involves the intersection of $r$ sets.  Then $$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n| = \sum_{r=1}^n [-1]^{(r+1)} T_r.$$

Comment: @drhab: How are identical bins supposed to be filled with distinct balls so that it is different from filling distinct bins with distinct balls ?

Comment: @trueblueanil If the bins are identical then e.g. outcome $(3,3,6)$ does not differ from outcome $(3,6,3)$. So it matters if you are counting that sort of outcomes. In this context however it is not relevant. $12$ balls are placed in $3$ boxes and the question is: what is the *probability* that at least one of the boxes will be containing $3$ balls? This only concerns quantitees and can be solved without paying any attention to distinguishable opposed to identical. The labels (also concerning the balls) are confusing and should be ignored.