$12$ Balls, $3$ bins. Find the Probability.
I'm not sure if a question like this might be discouraged, but I'm genuinely confused now.
I've been going over a question for some time, which is:
If $12$ distinct balls are to be placed in 3 identical boxes, then what's the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly 3 balls.
But my question is not about calculating the answer.
It is about knowing if the identity of the balls, or the bins actually matter here. And if it does, or does not, please give the solution of both ways to support your answer.
I'm aware that this problem is discussed here: If $12$ distinct balls are to be placed in $3$ identical boxes, then what's the probability that one of the boxes contains exactly $3$, balls.
, but that's what got me confused in the first place.
@math Lover (very reputed) says that https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4258115/1303459 the identity of the boxes doesn't matter. Even if you mark them later on with a different color sketch. And it seems right. But, the accepted answer by @true blue anil (again very reputed, though less voted) is something different. So, I feel that there needs to be more clarity about what is correct and what is not.
Also, with that argument, does it matter if the balls are identical or not, would it matter if after i distribute the balls in the bins, I mark them up, it shouldn't right?
So, please if someone can clarify it. I will really appreciate that. You don't have actually give an answer with a particular approach (much appreciated if you do though), but you have to support, compare your approaches and highlight their differences (or similarities). I'm not really keen to know the answer to this particular problem but to know if the answer would differ in the cases I talk about above.
The above marked question definitely is not sufficient to clear doubts. You can also mention some books or papers that talk about this thing.
I'm adding my own solutions to what my approach was.
Let's look at the case where the balls and the boxes are identical:
$$
[12, 0, 0], \quad
[11, 1, 0], \quad
[10, 2, 0], \quad
[10, 1, 1], \quad
[9, 3, 0], \quad
[9, 2, 1], \quad
[8, 4, 0], \quad
[8, 3, 1], \quad
[8, 2, 2], \quad
[7, 5, 0], \quad
[7, 3, 2], \quad
[7, 4, 1], \quad
[6, 6, 0], \quad
[6, 3, 3], \quad
[6, 5, 1], \quad
[6, 4, 2], \quad
[5, 5, 2], \quad
[5, 4, 3], \quad
[4, 4, 4]
$$
you can see that here are $5$ cases in which atleast one of the boxes contains $3$ balls. So, the probability in this case is $\dfrac{5}{19}$.
Now, let's look at another method, where the balls are identical but the boxes are distinct, I'm getting this to be $\dfrac{27}{91}$.
And none of them actually match the answer given by @math Lover.
What am I doing wrong?

Not sure what you are asking.  Indeed, whether the boxes are distinguishable or not, the answers are the same.  This is the same as saying that the probabilities of the various outcomes of the roll of two dice is unchanged regardless of whether you consider the dice to be distinct or not.  Is that what you are asking?

If that is your question, then it may be worth noting that, as a practical matter, it is often easier to imagine things are distinct.  In the dice example, this has the nice property that each outcome (e.g. $(3,4)$) has the same probability, namely $\frac 1{36}$.   If you regard the dice as indistinguishable then the probability of getting ${3,4}$ is twice the probability of getting ${3,3}$, for example.

sure, I understand what you mean. Also, in cases like picking 2 marbles from a sack that contains 2 red, and 2 green marbles, it would be more appropriate to consider them distinct. So, that picking two different colors has twice the probability (which is true), but in that case, can you compare the answers of the aforementioned people, that would be really helpful. They both have different answers using different approaches. Is one of them wrong? Or would it be incorrect to assume distinct boxes here.
See the top two answers in the question that I provided the link for.

I believe that at least some of those users are still active on the site, why not ask them?  The answers ought to be the same, either means of computation are valid.  Of course, arithmetic errors happen.

Yes, but that wasn't the only problem, I get two different answers myself. I should probably mention them

Yes, add your solutions to your post.  Indicate whether either of your answers matches those given in the old post.

FYIW:  I just did it and I note that my approach coincided with that of @MathLover.  I get $0.531535956$ for the actual value (noting that arithmetic error is always possible).

I note that the method sketched by the OP and fleshed out by true blue anil, is not correct .  As Math Lover rightly points out, you usually can't use combinatorial methods (like Stars and Bars)  to compute probability.  That's because the various arrangements counted by those methods are not equally probable.

Your method is wrong for the same reason.  Those outcomes you list are not equally probable.  $[12,0,0]$ is very unlikely, while $[3,4,5]$ is quite likely.

Oh, I see. So, even if the balls are given to be identical. It would be better to consider them distinct here, and calculate the probability. That would ensure repetition in outcomes like [3, 4, 5] for different balls, and manage the probability correctly. That's amazing. So, even though the boxes don't pose a problem being identical or unidentical for calculation, the balls do. Thanks. That's very clear now.

Do, you want to answer, so that I can mark that, or do I answer myself?

Feel free to answer yourself.  That way users here can check your work and the site can consider the question resolved.

@AnantTyagi: I have refined my answer, please see.

Here are my views on this, which may help you

Firstly, the question is vague, it doesn't mention whether exactly one box has exactly $3$, or more than one box can have exactly $3$, nor does it mention whether some box(es) can be empty. However, we can make our assumptions, this is not a major conceptual issue. I specify, for instance, that only one box has $3$, and each box must have at least $1$

Secondly, there is no doubt that the # of ways you can put distinct balls into identical boxes is different from the # of ways you can put distinct balls into distinct boxes. See, for example, here where the answers point out the difference.


The crux of the issue is whether the various patterns are equiprobable

[A] If we take it that each ball is put uniformly at random in the boxes, then these patterns aren't equiprobable, and the problem transforms in effect  into distinct balls in distinct boxes for computing probability

[B] If, on the other hand,  I  give a child a task to form in all possible ways three (unlabeled) heaps from $12$ marbles so that one heap has $3$ and no heap is empty, each pattern counts as just one way . and this count can be compared to forming all possible (unlabeled) heaps of $12$ with no heap empty, to get a different probabiiity. To be more precise, with this model, $Pr = [\binom{12}3{9\brace 2}]/{12\brace 3}. \approx 64.8\%$
After all, Stirling numbers of the second kind also model one type of reality !

The consensus on the earlier question you have quoted was that [A] is the appropriate model.



In the second model, you're not concerned with the probability of the events happening right? Just the number of ways the favorable outcome occurs out of all possible ways. And you mention that as another type of probability, do I understand that correctly?

$Pr = \frac{favorable; outcomes}{total; outcomes}\quad$ in both A and B.
In A, it is taken that balls are put in  randomly, so the model follows distinct balls into distinct boxes for computing Pr, whereas in B, i a child has been instructed to create as many distributions as possible into $3$ heaps with the provisos that heaps must not be empty, and that exactly one heap must have $3$ balls. Thus here the N heaps  created are equiprobable, and the numerator, while the denominator D is the number of heaps without the proviso that exactly one heap must have $3$ balls

Suppose you have $3$ identical boxes and $12$ identical balls, and distribute them randomly - there will be some probability that one of the boxes contains exactly three balls. Now I turn on a black light, and it turns out that all of the items were actually marked - you realize they are not identical, they are in fact all unique. The probability that one of the boxes contains exactly $3$ balls has obviously not changed by turning on the black light after you've already distributed the balls! It doesn't matter whether the objects are indistinguishable or not.

This seems absolutely correct, but I'm getting two different answers using two approaches, (identical balls identical boxes, and identical balls, distinct boxes), if you want, I can add my solution to the question, or you can yourself add their solutions in the answer if you would like to check it out.

First, what $Nuclear Hoagie$ mentions, is absolutely correct. The identity of the objects doesn't matter at calculating the probability. But, your method actually does. When I mentioned the cases in my question, they consider all the cases that are possible, but the problem is that they aren't equally likely.
As $lulu$ mentioned, the probability of $[3, 4, 3]$ happening, is much more than $[12, 0, 0]$. So, I can't calculate probability this way (I can't consider the probability of all cases happening to be $\dfrac{1}{19}$). Instead, it would be better (even the balls given are identical) to consider them distinct. That way, we can account for the different cases of $[3, 4, 3]$ happening.
And the answer of $math Lover@$ matches the answer of $lulu$ which is equal to $0.531535956$, so, I'll go with that for the correct one.
Chris Piech in his probability lecture has mentioned this.
