# Line up objects in each box after using Stirling number of second kind?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, stirling-numbers

If I have *n* distinct objects and *k* identical boxes, I can use Stirling number of second kind to distribute them in every posible way so that every box contains atleast one object. I would like to know if there is a way to line up those objects in every box once they are all divided? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Does *[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256025/arranging-books-in-bookshelves-with-the-capacity-of-each-shelf-given)* answer your question ?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the [Lah numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number), given by the simple formula $\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$ That is, line up the books in $n!$ ways, place $k-1$ dividers in the $n-1$ spaces between them in $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to get $k$ ordered groups, then divided by $k!$ since we do not care about the order of the groups (this is valid since all books are distinct and the groups are nonempty, so each of the $k!$ permutations of an arrangement is different) .

Answer (score 1):

In the language of combinatorial classes from *Analytic Combinatorics* we
have Stirling numbers  of the first kind, counting sets of cycles,
Stirling numbers of the  second kind, counting sets of sets and Lah
numbers counting sets of  tuples, where the cycles, sets and tuples
always contain at least one  element. We get the class specifications

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})),\;
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})),\;
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

giving the bivariate GFs

$$\exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right),\;
\exp(u(\exp(z)-1)),\;
\exp\left(u\frac{z}{1-z}\right).$$

We get for Lah numbers the closed form

$$n! [z^n] [u^k] \exp\left(u\frac{z}{1-z}\right)
= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}
\\ = \frac{n!}{k!} [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
= \frac{n!}{k!} {n-1\choose k-1}.$$