# Distinguishable balls in distinguishable urns of a maximal size

Tags: combinatorics

Let's assume we have $u\geqslant 1$ distinguishable urns, each of which can hold at most $m\geqslant 1$ balls, and $b\geqslant 1$ distinguishable balls.  In how many ways can we

(a) distribute all $b$ balls into the urns?

(b) distribute any number of balls up to $b$ into the urns?

The final configuration does matter. (E.g., for $u=2$, $m=3$, $b=4$,  urns U1,U2, and balls B1–B4, the configurations U1={B1,B2},U2={B3,B4} and U1={B3,B4},U2={B1,B2} and U1={B1,B2,B3},U2={B4} are three different configurations.)

The time order of putting the balls into urns doesn't matter. (For example, putting balls B1 and B2 into urn U1 and balls B3 and B4 into urn U2 gives the same result as putting B2 into U1, then B3 into U2, then B1 into U1, and then B4 into U2; both distribution oders lead to the same set {B1,B2} being the contents of U1 and {B3,B4} the contents of U2.)

In a boringly precise formula language, we count the number of tuples of the form $(U_1,\dots,U_u)$ where $\bigcup_{i=1}^u U_i=\{1,\dotsc,b\}$ (for (a); $\bigcup_{i=1}^u U_i \subseteq \{1,\dotsc,b\}$ for (b)), and $\lvert U_i\rvert \leqslant m$ ($1\leqslant i\leqslant u$), and the family of sets $\{U_i\mid 1\leqslant i\leqslant u\}$ is pairwise disjoint.

I need an exact closed-form expression, nonrecursive and involving only elementary operations, exponentiation, logarithm, factorials, big sums, big products, and multinomial coefficients. If unavailable, a polynomial-time algorithm (in the length of the input consisting of the binary representations of $b$, $m$, and $u$) would be great. If even that unavailable, a good lower bound (or an asymptotic formula with exact error margins) would be great. If even that is unavailable, a recursive formula would be great.

Remark. In my application, $u \leqslant b \leqslant mu$ and $m \leqslant b$; these assumptions might hypothetically help.

Comment: might this help you ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420

Comment: @GCab I think the balls are indistinguishable there. Do we simply have to multiply their formula with the factorial of the number of the balls, i.e., $b! N(b,m,u)$ ?

Comment: There is likely no formula for this answer. What kind of answer are you looking for? An approximation, or an algorithm to compute the number?

Comment: @MikeEarnest An exact closed-term formula, hopefully nonrecursive, hopefully with only elementary operations, factorials, big sums, and multinomial coefficients.. A polynomial-time algorithm (in the length of the binary representation of the numbers $u, m, b$) would also do.

Comment: you say that the balls are *distinguishable*, but then you also say *"The order of putting the balls into an urn or into urns doesn't matter"*. It is not clear what you want to do. Please put an example with small $b,m,u$ of the configurations you consider as distinct.

Comment: @GCab That's right. What matters is the final result of putting the balls into the urns, and not how you get this result. I've just added examples.

Comment: I would like to have your feedback on my answer ..

Comment: @GCab Many, many, many thanks!!!!! Will definitely do!!!!!! (Though, as I unfortunately have to admit, it won't happen right away.)

Comment: ok, take your time ..

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood what you mean to say

- you have $b$ dist. balls, i.e. labeled $1,2, \ldots , b$. You shuffle (permute) them , i.e. you relabel them,  -> no change wrt if they are labelled  orderly;
- you take the balls one by one, in sequence, and put it into any one of the free spaces available in the urn;
- since you do not take into account the order of the balls within each urn, that is the same as starting with the original labelling $1,2, \ldots ,b$,
  deposit the balls sequentially and end up with a *u-ple* (or *list*) of
  *sub-sets*(i.e. ordered) taken from the set $\{1,2, \ldots , b \}$ , and having $0,1, \ldots, max=m$ elements, that is to say something like
  $$
  \left[ {\left\{ {1,4,6} \right\},\left\{ \emptyset  \right\},\left\{ {2,5} \right\},\left\{ \emptyset  \right\},\left\{ 3 \right\}} \right]
  $$

Under this acception, and in particular regarding the ball laying process, and with a given number $b$ of balls (case a) ) all the *u-ples* are equi-probable.

That premised, allow me to change your symbols
$$
{\rm N}{\rm .}\,{\rm balls}:\;b\; \Rightarrow \;s\;,\quad {\rm balls/box}\,
{\rm max}:\;m\; \Rightarrow \;r\;,\quad {\rm N}{\rm .}\,{\rm boxes}:\;\;u\; \Rightarrow \;m
$$
so that I can introduce a sketch I already prepared time ago for myself.

[image: Balls_in_urn_Restrained_1]

I hope that the sketch be quite self explanatory: we start from the *Sets of non-empty sub-sets* (counted by $ L_{\,b\,U\,D\,N} $) and from that we compute
the *Lists of non-empty subsets* which clearly are $m!$ times the precedent, and the *cumulative*, i.e.  *possibly empty sub-sets* case follow immediately.

Thus the key here are the **Restrained Stirling N. 2nd kind**.
You can refer for instance to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316505001895).

I will just remark here that they are related to the [Bell Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials)
and summarize a couple of the equivalent ways to define them
$$
\eqalign{
  & L_{\,b\,U\,D\,N} (s,r,m) = \left\{ \matrix{  s \cr  m \cr}  \right\}_{\,r}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,p_{\,1}  \le p_{\,2}  \le  \cdots  \le p_{\,m} \, \le \,r}  \cr 
   {p_{\,1}  + p_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + p_{\,m}  = s}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {{1 \over {t_{\,1} !t_{\,2} !\, \cdots \,t_{\,m} !}}
\left( \matrix{ s \cr   p_{\,1} ,\,p_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,p_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,t_{\,j} \,\left( {\, \le \,m} \right)}  \cr 
   {t_{\,1}  + t_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + t_{\,r}  = m}  \cr 
   {1\,t_{\,1}  + 2\,t_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + r\,t_{\,r}  = s}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {\,{{s!} \over {\prod\limits_{1\, \le \,\,k\, \le \,r}
 {t_{\,k} !\left( {k!} \right)^{\,t_{\,k} } } }}}  \cr} 
$$
In the second line, the sum is taken over all the partitions $(p_1,p_2, \ldots , p_m)$ of $s$ into $m$ parts
of max size $r$.
$t_k$ counts the number of times that the part $p_k$ appears : $0 \le t_k \le m, \; (t_1+t_2+ \cdots + t_m)=m$ .
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left[ {p_{\,1} ,\,p_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,p_{\,m} } \right]\;:\;
{\rm partition}\,{\rm of}\,s\,{\rm into}\,m\,{\rm parts}\, \le \,r  \cr 
  & \underbrace {p_{\,1} }_{t_{\,1} } < \,\underbrace {p_{\,2}  =
 p_{\,3}  =  \cdots  = p_{\,q} }_{t_{\,2} }\, <
 \underbrace {p_{\,q + 1} }_{t_{\,q + 1} } <  \cdots  <
 \underbrace {p_{\,m - u}  =  \cdots  = p_{\,m} }_{t_{\,m - u} } \cr} 
$$
In the third line, we rank the possible parts as $1 \le k \le r$ and assign to each the number of times $0 \le t_k \le m$
that the part $k$ appears in the partition.

Then, allowing some parts to be null, we get
$$
N_{\,b\,U\,D\,N} (s,r,m) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,p_{\,1}  \le p_{\,2}  \le  \cdots  \le p_{\,m} \, \le \,r}  \cr 
   {p_{\,1}  + p_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + p_{\,m}  = s}  \cr 
 } } \right.} {{1 \over {t_{\,1} !t_{\,2} !\, \cdots \,t_{\,m} !}}
\left( \matrix{  s \cr   p_{\,1} ,\,p_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,p_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)} 
$$

While, passing from *partitions* to [Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
respectively "strong" and "weak", we get
$$
L_{\,b\,D\,D\,N} (s,r,m) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {1\, \le \,c_{\,j} \, \le \,r}  \cr  {c_{\,1}  + c_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + c_{\,m}  = s}  \cr  } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{ s \cr  c_{\,1} ,\,c_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,c_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)} 
$$
$$
N_{\,b\,D\,D\,N} (s,r,m) = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{
   {0\, \le \,c_{\,j} \, \le \,r}  \cr {c_{\,1}  + c_{\,2}  + \, \cdots  + c_{\,m}  = s}  \cr } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{  s \cr  c_{\,1} ,\,c_{\,2} ,\, \cdots ,c_{\,m}  \cr}  \right)} 
$$

You may verify that the above formulations in terms of multinomials satisfy the relations shown in the sketch.

Also, taking for example $r = 3$,  the above formulas check with
$ L_{\,b\,U\,D\,N} (s,3,m)$  : [OEIS A111246](http://oeis.org/A111246)
$ L_{\,b\,D\,D\,N} (s,3,m)$ : [OEIS A189804](http://oeis.org/A189804)
$ N_{\,b\,D\,D\,N} (s,3,m)$ : [OEIS A234574](http://oeis.org/A234574)

Comment: Almost, as you wish to say $\emptyset$ instead of $\{\emptyset\}$. What we count is the number of tuples of the form $(U_1,\dots,U_u)$ where $\lvert U_i\rvert \leqslant m$ ($1\leqslant i\leqslant u$), and the sets $U_i$ are pairwise disjoint ($1\leqslant i\leqslant u$), and $\bigcup_{i=1}^u U_i=\{1,\dotsc,b\}$ (for (a); $\subseteq$ for (b)) .

Comment: Something is wrong: in your middle formula, $t_1, \dotsc, t_m$ are not bound but used.

Comment: yes, sorry, I omitted to clarify about the $t_k$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no non-recursive closed form expression for this. However, it can be effectively computed as follows.

If $N(b,m,u)$ is the number of placements of exactly $b$ balls, then
$$
N(b,m,u)=\sum_{i=0}^{\min(b,m)} \binom{b}{i}N(b-i,m,u-1)
$$
which follows by conditioning on all the ways to place at most $m$ balls in the first urn.

This lets you compute $N(b,m,u)$ by filling out the table indexed by $\{0,1,\dots,b\}\times \{1,\dots,u\}$ whose entry in the $r^{th}$ row and $c^{th}$ columns is $N(r,m,c)$. Each entry takes $O(m)$ arithmetic operations to fill out, so the complexity is $O(b\times m\times u)=O((mu)^2)$.

For a faster algorithm, you can use exponential generating functions to write
$$
N(b,m,u)=b![x^b]\left(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^{m}}{m!}\right)^u
$$
The notation $[x^n]f(x)$ refers to the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial (or power series) $f(x)$.

This shows that $N(b,m,u)$ can be computed using $\log u$ polynomial multiplications between polynomials of degree $b$ (use exponentiation by squaring, and only keep track of terms up to degree $b$). If you use FFT multiplication, the complexity is $$O(b\log b\times \log u)=O(m\times u\times \log(mu)\times \log u).$$ Again, this complexity is measured in number of arithmetic operations.

Finally, both of these methods actually compute the entire list $\{N(a,m,u):0\le a\le b\}$ at no extra cost, so you can compute the number of ways to place at most $b$ balls by adding up all the values of $N(a,m,u)$ for $a\in \{0,1,\dots,b\}$.

Comment: I see you use $\min\{b,m\}$. So I've just added one more assumption from my application, which might (or might not) help: $m\leqslant b$; this would simplify $\min\{b,m\}$ to $m$ in the outermost recursion step (but not your recursive formula).

Comment: @GeekestGeek Thank you for the extra info. It does not affect any of my analysis, other then allowing you to replace $\min(b,m)$ with $m$.

Comment: I also suppose you assume unit time for each elementary operation. I'm not sure whether this assumption is that well justified. The output numbers might get big, after all.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Yes, I should have said, I measured complexity in terms of # arithmetic ops. The magnitude of the integers being added is something like $O((b+u)!)$.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what are the reasons for there being no non-recursive closed form expression for this?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I have no proof, but I would wager my math license on it, just based on experience with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks! Then I suggest you downtone your first sentence, e.g., by adding "IMHO" or in a similar way. We don't want to make the reader think there is a proof.

Comment: And as for FFT multiplication, I cannot check it but have to do quite a bit of catching up, I'm afraid…

Comment: I would like to know your opinion on my approach